# Highlighting words across dom nodes

Tags: javascript, html, regex, search, highlight

I have some messy html due to OCR that I need to highlight. Words are sometimes split between dom nodes. I need to search for any user input text and add a highlight span around wherever that text appears in the html.

Example

```html
<div id="content">
  <span>my birthday par<span>ty is today</span></span>
</div>
```

The search term here would be "birthday party". I have tried to regex but am unable to capture the right group.
(regex noob) `` new RegExp(`([${searchTerm}]+)!?<[^>]*>`, 'gi') `` which is producing `["y birthday pa<span>", "day</span>"]`

I would need to capture something like `my Birthday par<span>ty` or the index of that so I can wrap it in another element to highlight.

Ideal outcome would be

```html
<div id='content'>
  <span>my<mark class='highlight'>birthday par<span>ty</mark> is today</span><span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps: https://regex101.com/r/wpiPz1/1

Comment: Your ideal outcome is not valid HTML. You can’t have intersecting markup like that.